# Generic functions for multiple CoreData entities

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, codable

I'm currently developing an application that keeps track of 5 CoreData entities, and is synchronized with a server so far I've been doing some custom classes for synchronization and the corresponding Codable structures to upload and receive the information to and from the server. I've developed an extension for each of the entities, to map the information from the Codable structure to the CoreData entities.

---

My problem is that I have this 5 classes which do exactly the same, with the slight change of the entities and the structures, I would love to do a generalized `Class` that could keep the information synchronized just by adding the URL parameter. But the problem I get is that because all the entities map differently the information because of their own variables I can't use a generic parameter which is `NSManagedObject` because it won't recognize the extended function, here is a brief example:

---

### Example of classes:

```swift
class SincronizacionCampos{
...
     /**
     Eliminar los campos seleccionados de la nube

     Se envían los ids de los campos que deben de ser eliminados de la nube personal del usuario

     - Parameters:
        - ids: Lista de los ids de los campos que deben de ser eliminados
        - salida: Llamada al terminar la ejecución de la solicitud
     */
    fileprivate func eliminar(ids: Set<Int32>?, o informacion: [CampoSerializer]?, _ salida: (()->())? = nil){
        guard let token = InfoUsuario.shared.token else{
            salida?()
            return
        }
        let lista = ListaCamposSerializer()
        lista.campos = [CampoSerializer]()
        if let info = informacion {
            lista.campos = info
        } else{
            ids?.forEach { (id) in
                let ser = CampoSerializer.init(id: id, uuid: nil, verificado: false, hcpIguales: false, nombre: "", sumaPar: 0, par: "", hcp1: "", hcp2: "", colorHandicap1: 0, colorHandicap2: 0, idDeUsuario: nil, nombreDeUsuario: nil)
                lista.campos?.append(ser)
            }
        }
        ConexionServer.shared.solicitudDELETE(con: .camposDePerfil, parametros: lista, token: token, desde: nil) { (hayError, descripcion) in
            guard hayError == false else{
                Logging.shared.escribirNuevo(descripcion)
                salida?()
                return
            }
            salida?()
        }
    }
...
```

And the same function in my class of *Amigos*:

```swift
class SincronizacionAmigos{
...
     /**
     Eliminar jugadores del servidor

     Envia una solicitud al servidor para eliminar los jugadores que han sido eliminados localmente.

     - Parameters:
         - ids: Set de IDs de los jugadores que han sido eliminados
         - salida: Llamada al terminar la solicitud
     */
    fileprivate func eliminar(ids: Set<Int32>?, o informacion: [AmigosSerializer]?, _ salida: (()->())? = nil){
        guard let token = InfoUsuario.shared.token else{
            salida?()
            return
        }
        let lista = ListaAmigosSerializer()
        lista.amigos = [AmigosSerializer]()
        if let info = informacion{
            lista.amigos = info
        } else{
            ids?.forEach { (id) in
                let ser = AmigosSerializer.init(id: id, nombreCompleto: nil, nombreCorto: "", ventaja: 0, casados: false, ultimaActualizacion: nil, apuestas: "", numeroDeTelefono: nil, uuid: nil, idJugadorCloud: nil)
                lista.amigos?.append(ser)
            }
        }
        ConexionServer.shared.solicitudDELETE(con: .amigosDePerfil, parametros: lista, token: token, desde: nil) { (hayError, descripcion) in
            guard hayError == false else{
                Logging.shared.escribirNuevo(descripcion)
                guard let pendientes = lista.amigos else{
                    salida?()
                    return
                }
                self.agregarSolicitudFallida(informacion: pendientes, con: .DELETE)
                salida?()
                return
            }
            salida?()
        }
    }
...
}
```

This is just a brief example but the idea in this one is that I can't use the same serializer because the serializers are different. I would appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction and if you need any extra information just say it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could basically create a PAT which has a type which is again a protocol and extract your common function with generics. Something like this,

```
protocol AnotherSerializer: class {
}

protocol Serializer: class {
    associatedtype SerializerType: AnotherSerializer

    var list: [SerializerType] { set get }

    init()

}
```

And your synchronization class would have generic function like this,

```
class Sincronizacion {

    fileprivate func eliminar<T: Serializer, U>(type: T.Type, ids: Set<Int32>?, o informacion: [U]?, _ salida: (()->())? = nil) where T.SerializerType == U {
        guard let token = InfoUsuario.shared.token else{
            salida?()
            return
        }
        let lista = T()
        lista.list = [U]()

        if let info = informacion {
            lista.list = info
        } else {
            // other code here
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Note that this could get pretty messy if you make `AnotherSerializer` a PAT again. It is good to avoid them and make some other design considerations, since it can make code more complex and difficult to understand. But, if you can limit the scopr of your design, you are pretty good with this solution.

Comment: Thank you I'll consider my options to see what's best for the code.